# Swift - Assigning struct to a var result always nil

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, struct

i have a little problem with this simple code. I have a var **selectedItem** of type **MyStruct** that is alway **nil**

I have this class

```
class Test: UIViewController {

var selectedItem: MyStruct?
var collectionData: [OtherStruct]

....

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

     selectedItem = collectionData[indexPath.row].item
}
```

Then selected item is always nil.

```
struct OtherStruct {
    var item: MyStruct
    .....
    .....

    init(item: MyStruct) {
        self.item = item
    }
}

struct MyStruct: Codable {
    var test: String
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        ...
    }
}
```

My variable **selectedItem** is always nil. Why?

if i do

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

  let localeSelectedItem = collectionData[indexPath.row].item
}
```

localeSelectedItem is not nil and is of MyStruct type.

**EDIT**
If i change

```
var selectedItem: MyStruct?
```

to

```
var selectedItem: Any?
```

and then i do

```
if let item = selectedItem as? MyStruct {
}
```

works

Please note, that collectionData[indexPath.row].item is of type MyStruct (checked with the debugger)

Comment: Show the cellForRow method.

Comment: When and where are you detecting that it is nil?

Comment: In didSelectItemAt, after assigning it, with the debbuger i see that is nil.

Comment: After getting the data are you reloading your `tableView`?

Comment: Is BetslipCustomItem the same as OtherStruct?

Comment: Yep, was an error.